# MVC SQL No Connection String Named Could Be Found in the Application Config File EF6

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have searched through a number of questions([No Connection String Named MyEntities Could Be Found In The Application Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622408/no-connection-string-named-myentities-could-be-found-in-the-application-config)), but most seem to deal with multiple projects in a solution, in this case I have only one project in one solution.  Also this is my first MVC Project with EF6.  When going to add a controller I get this error:

[image]

This is my Web.Config

[image]

And This is My Solution Explorer

[image]

I know the error references an Application Config File, but I do not have an app Config file, nor do I know where to put it or how to create it.

EDIT, Here is the code for the db context

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
     public ApplicationDbContext() : base("name=DBConnection"){}
     public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<zzz.Models.Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you show some code, specifically your DbContext? you most likely aren't specifying the right connection to look at in there.

Comment: do you have your DbContext in separate project which compiling into dll?

Comment: No, it is all in one project

Comment: `base("name=DBConnection")` this looks wrong, I believe this will try to find a `<add name="name=DBConnection" connectionStr...`

Comment: Change to `base("WhateverHiddenDBConnection")`

Comment: Changing to base("DBConnection") causes adding a controller to just create a local db instead of connect to the SQL server