# Getting a error about no connection string being in the application configuration file. Why?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I'm getting an error that doesn't make any sense to me. I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.3, class first based upon existing database. When I created the DbContext class using EF I called it PrismSpecMap. There most certainly is a class by that name, and its a public class. (It is in a folder named Data; I don't know if that will make a difference or not.) I get an error message from Visual Studio 2013 saying, "No connection string named 'PrismSpecMap' could be found in the application config file." But that doesn't make sense; it is there, I've opened the app.config file and it's there. And what also doesn't make any sense is I can compile and run it on my dev box.

Why am I getting this error when it is in the app.config file? How do I "fix" whatever it is that's broken/not happy?

Comment: Post the relevant section of the app.config file and double check your spelling.

Comment: Can you paste the connection string from the app config (with pw and username removed obv) ? Also what kind of startup project are you using?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622408/no-connection-string-named-myentities-could-be-found-in-the-application-config

Comment: Here's the relevant code from the App.Config file:

    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="PrismSpecMap" connectionString="data   source=SOMESERVER;initial catalog=STDPrismTest;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check correctness of connectionstring name. Then check that connection string is added in a **startup** project. All others app.config or web.config files will be ignored. Whenever you have a few projects in the solution configuration file is used from main project.