# No connection string named 'MarketingEntities' could be found in the application config file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

> No connection string named 'MarketingEntities' could be found in the application config file

[image: Error]

All the googling in the world came up with solutions that dont work for me.

1. Its a single project application, there is no `MyApp.Repository` or anything else, just `MyApp`, so the solution to set the UI project as startup will not work for me.
2. Connection is in my `App.config` (there is no web.config) 
   [image]
3. Ive deleted both `bin` and `obj` folders, did a clean. cleared out temp (via ccleaner). Running the app works, no problem. Normally, id ignore this and move on but in this case, I cant because I need to design something....

What do?!

E: The code that calls the settings file

```
public partial class MarketingEntities : DbContext
{
    public MarketingEntities() : base("name=MarketingEntities")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `add key` instead of `add name` edit: can you show us the code you're using to retrieve the setting?

Comment: my code to retrieve the settings? im not using any per-say. im using the default generated code from EF6. using `key` instead, same results. app runs, cant design. and now the config file says `key attribute cannot be used`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622408/no-connection-string-named-myentities-could-be-found-in-the-application-config

this might solve your issue

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Include the error message and the app.config as text, it is just short enough.

Comment: @tom which one? those answers are points 1 and 2 in my question

Comment: @highboi SO posts (answers especially) are meant to help all future visitors.  Pictures dont work in a Google search.  Once in a while they are called for illustrate a UI issue, but not as a substitute for typing in your error text

Comment: try `public MarketingEntities() :base("MarketingEntities")`