# How to handle "No connection string named 'RestaurentEntities' could be found in the application config file" in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, syncfusion

I am trying a project on WinForms. I made a Form name `Dashboard` and User Control name `DashboardScreen`.
`Dashboard` basically will have many User Controls on it like `DashboardScreen`, `InventoryScreen`, `SettingsScreen` etc. These screens are small and Dock in main parent form `Dashboard` so when user click on button, corresponding user control comes to the front using `DashboardScreen.BringToFront()`

These user controls are implementing `Entity Framework V 6.4.0` User controls and Main Dashboard Form works fine when I do not use Entity Framework on these controls. Whenever I use Entity Framework as `RestaurentEntities DB = new RestaurentEntities();` to utilize database services the Main Dashboard Form gives the following Error in Design Mode.

> No connection string named 'RestaurentEntities' could be found in the application config file.

Second Error is

> The variable 'dashboardScreen' is either undeclared or was never assigned.

Given is my configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings><add name="RestaurentEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=YASIR\SQLDEVENV;initial catalog=Restaurent;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No connection string named 'MyEntities' could be found in the application config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622408/no-connection-string-named-myentities-could-be-found-in-the-application-config)

Comment: Most likely you will need to add the connectionStrings to the .config file of the project that is actually calling the new RestaurentEntities object

Answer (score 1):

if you want to drag and drop a UserControl in a form and the control in the constructor method or OnLoad method has access to EntityFramework and the EntityFramework access is created by referenced project you must include into your code something like:

```
 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
 {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            //access to EntityFramework
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your connectionStrings to below:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="RestaurentEntities" 
   connectionString="data source=YASIR\SQLDEVENV;initial catalog=Restaurent;integrated 
   security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And make sure that

your Dbcontext constructor is like

```
    public RestaurentEntities ()
        : base("name=RestaurentEntities")
    {


    }
```

Comment: It do not works. It gives an error of "Entity Framework: The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file"