# app.config location in entity framework

Tags: .net, frameworks, entity, config, arcmap

My solution consist of three projects:
1. startup class library .net 2 project which calls external application(arcmap).
2. Entity framework protect .net 4.5 class library.
3. Project which calls entity framework, and doing a query. Also version 4.5.

I can't change the startup project to be .net 4.5.

when I try to query from the third project I get an exception that "no connection string named 'entities' could be find in application config file".

The connectionstring appears in app.config file, and works great when I use it in a single .net 4.5 project with entity framework.

I tried to put the app.config under any of my projects and under the solution but I always get this exception.

Does anyone know how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This sounds like a project migration issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978017/no-connection-string-named-myapplicationentities-could-be-found-in-the-applica might help.

Comment: I didn't find in the question above anything that can help..