# Interaction.Triggers causing 'XamlParseException' at design time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Did anyone else encounter this problem? I am using Visual Stuido 2015 Prof. and when I use Interaction.Triggers in an ItemsControl.ItemTemplate the designer throws following exeption:

```
'XamlParseException: Collection property 'System.Windows.Controls.AnyControl'.'Triggers' is null.'
```

(AnyControl: If I put the trigger inside an Image, it's Image etc.)

The program is´running as expected at runtime without any problems.

That's a little annoying since I have to comment/uncomment the triggers everytime when I want to see the designer view.

Example code snippet part:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Currencies}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="3,3,20,3">

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.MouseEnterCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" 
                                                           CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                        <Image Width="50" Height="50"
                               Source="{Binding Settings.ActiveImage}" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="30000">
```

etc.

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43642741/5976576)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with Visual Studio 2015.
I upgraded to Visual Studio 2017 and it's working.