# ConnectionString Not Found in App.Config but is Definitely There

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am getting an issue that I have seen posted before but the answers seem only applicable to ASP.NET MVC, whereas I am using WPF (with Entity Framework).

My XAML designer in VS currently looks like this:

[image]

This is on a `UserControl` where the code is very simple:

```
<UserControl x:Class="door_system.Views.HomeView"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                 xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:door_system.ViewModels"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModels:HomeViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

So my project setup looks like so:

[image]

There is only one `app.config` file that definitely contains the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MicrotrakContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MicrotrakModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MicrotrakModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MicrotrakModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=*******;initial catalog=MicrotrakEvolution;user id=******;password=********;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I build the project there are no errors. When I run the project it performs without error too. Is this a bug I have discovered?

Aside from name changes I have two other projects that are setup in almost exactly the same way, both build and run without issue.

The Task calling the Context in `HomeViewModel`:

```
private Task LoadTransactionsTask()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var context = new MicrotrakContext())
        {
            AllTransactions = new ObservableCollection<Transaction>(
                (from record in context.Transactions
                    select record)
                .Where(x => x.CreationTime >= DateTime.Today)
                .ToList());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where's the *code* and the actual exception? Have you tried debugging your code? XAML doesn't query databases. How do you define and use your EF context?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Please see the edit.

Comment: What does the *stack trace* show? And please, please, please, ***PLEASE*** post the connection string text, not an indivible black screenshot of the connection string text. That looks like a blurred EF connection string. The element doesn't look like a blurred *EF config* section.

Comment: "My designer in VS currently looks like this" Are you referring to your XAML designer, EF Model designer or something else?

Comment: @jcruz XAML designer.

Comment: This is what I use for my view model `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"` you will need to tweak it to your needs though.

Comment: @XAMlMAX It's strange that I would need to do that because as I said I have other projects the same as this one, without using `d:DataContext` that have no issues

Comment: It will, if the UserControl is in another assembly. Say you main window is in `.exe` and this UC would be in `.dll` then it will not have access to the config file.

Comment: @XAMlMAX How can I check which assembly each is in?

Comment: It will be down to your solution. Only you can know where your UserControl is.

Comment: @XAMlMAX from the image of my project setup above I just cannot see how they can be anywhere different from each other....

Comment: I can't view images as I am at work and here we use proxy for internet access.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I am using `d:DataContext` now and same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why the VS Designer throws exception

Some of your application code (e.g. `HomeViewModel`) is executed by the XAML designer process. Your code (e.g. `new MicrotrakContext()`) looks for configuration file of the current process, not your app.config.

## How to fix it

You should prevent your application to access database, file system or any other I/O operations and provide some design time data instead.

I've described some techniques here: [Daniel Turan's answer to: Does mmvm stop the ability for Visual Studio designer to show XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43640361/does-mvvm-stop-the-ability-for-the-visual-studio-designer-to-show-xaml/43642741#43642741)

Basically, you can check in your code:

```
if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(someDepenencyObject))
{
    LoadDesignTimeData();
}
else
{
    LoadRealData();
}
```

**EDIT:**
my prefered way is DesignTime viewmodel:

```
public class HomeViewModelDesignTime : HomeViewModel
{
    protected override Task LoadTransactionsTask()
    {
       //load some hard coded design time data
    }
}
```

tell the designer to use this class:

```
<UserControl x:Class="door_system.Views.HomeView"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:HomeViewModelDesignTime, IsDesignTimeCreatable=true}"
```

you can than instatiate you real ViewModel in codebehind for example.

TIP: create your own Project Item Template in Visual Studio, that will create UserControl with ViewModel and DesignTimeViewModel for you, so you don't have do it manually each time.

Comment: From the XAML code I have in the question above I can't see that I am doing any operations like that? That is all the XAML code I have above. Why would the code of the designer be looking for the config file?

Comment: because you are instantiating your `HomeViewModel` in xaml, and it is acessing database by entity framework. I guess you call `LoadTransactionsTask` from HomeViewModel's ctor

Comment: Thanks for your time. Should I instead instantiate my `ViewModel` in codebehind rather than XAML?

Comment: XAML should definitelly have information about ViewModel's type. You can do it either by instantiating ViewModel in xaml, just like you did, or alternatively using `{d:DesignInstance}` markup extension. See my edit and the link provided in my answer.

Comment: Update - even with your edit I am still getting a message saying it cant find the connection string, however now it is in the XAML code itself and I can see the designer.

Comment: Its because you are still calling db somewhere. You can debug xaml designer, it will show you where the exception is thrown. Google debugging xaml designer

Answer (score 0):

Is you code compiling properly at this point:
`using (var context = new MicrotrakContext())` <-- Does it know what MicrotrakContext() is?

You can do a quick search for: `: base("name=` the expectation would be MicrotrakContext will be the value following `name=`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Next time post your questions in comments, not in answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This happens because you are trying to do some database access in design time. To solve this problem:

1. Remove all the code from the User Control constructor (just let there the InicializeComponent method); The removed code, **should be inserted in the userControl_Load** method;
2. Just **verify if it is in design mode** before executing the methods that have queries.

   ```
   if (!DesignMode)
   {
     // Functions that have any database access should be here (eg. queries, inserts, etc)
   }
   ```