# DB First ,ASP Net Core 2.1, EF6 : InvalidOperationException: No connection string named 'DataContext' could be found in the application config file

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, database-connection, connection-string, db-first

I am using asp net core 2.1 and EF 6, using **DB First**.
My connectionString in App.Config:

I have this error:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: No connection string named 'DataContext' could be found in the application config file.
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ConnectionHasModel()

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="APWebDataContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=;initial catalog=;persist security info=True;user id=;password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Can you show us your DataContext ? This issue may related to the content in your DataContext, you can refer to this ： https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978017/no-connection-string-named-myapplicationentities-could-be-found-in-the-applica

Comment: public partial class APWebDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public APWebDataContext()
            : base("name=APWebDataContext")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
    
        public virtual DbSet<xxxxxx> x{ get; set; }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

According to the content of `APWebDataContext` you provided, the cause of the error is this:

```
public APWebDataContext() : base("name=APWebDataContext") { }
```

You don't need to add `name` here.

Modify your APWebDataContext as follows:

```
public partial class APWebDataContext : DbContext 
{ 
  public APWebDataContext() : base("APWebDataContext") { } 

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  { 
    throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException(); 
  } 

  public virtual DbSet<xxxxxx> x{ get; set;} 

}
```

Comment: I am using DB first not code first. I found this article from microsoft which explained how to have separate project in EF6 with asp.net core. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-2.1  still this didnt help me that much a I am using DB first and my connection string differs from another type and I cant modify that.